# Use series expansion to show limit converges to standard normal?

Tags: statistics

So I have what the mgf of Z is but I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do in this problem? I don't really get what's going in the answer. I thought maybe it's just plugging in but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong.[image]

this is part a
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful how you write the MGF, especially regarding what's in the exponent. In your previous exercise you should have gotten

$$
M_Z(t)=e^{-\sqrt\lambda t}e^{\lambda(e^{ t/{\sqrt\lambda}}-1)}=
\exp({-\sqrt\lambda t -\lambda +\lambda e^{t/\sqrt\lambda}})
$$
as the MGF for $Z$. (Notice that $e^{t/{\sqrt\lambda}}-1$ is in the exponent.) To evaluate this as $\lambda\to\infty$, you indeed just plug in the series expansion for $e^{t/\sqrt\lambda}$, and cancel things, then let $\lambda\to\infty$.

Comment: Ahhh.... I guess I got confused because in question a it says we're finding Mz(t) ? I added a picture to my question to clarify.

Comment: Yep, question a has the right form for the MGF of $Z$.

Comment: Oh okay cool (I got sloppy so I accidentally put everything a bit lower)--- one last question, did you get $$ \exp({-\sqrt\lambda t -\lambda +\lambda e^{t/\sqrt\lambda}}) $$ by just simplifying ?

Comment: I got that last expression by algebra: using $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$, we get the exponent to be $-\sqrt\lambda t+\lambda (e^{t/\sqrt\lambda}-1)=-\sqrt\lambda t + \lambda e^{t/\sqrt\lambda} - \lambda$ after distributing the $\lambda$ onto $(e^{t/\sqrt\lambda } - 1)$

Comment: Ohhhh, I see!! Thank you very much for explaining!